# Headers is treated as Data in spreadsheet query through JS

Tags: google-visualization, spreadsheet

I am trying to read data from Spreadsheet using google visualization query. i am sending axios request to my spreadsheet. after getting response the output shows 1st column as data itself instead of headers. I am sending axios request to url.

** let url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${id}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&tq=${encodedQuery}&gid=${gid}` **

What do I need to change to get all the headers as it should be or all as the data also works fine. is there something wrong with the spreadsheet. **I have deleted my sheet and recreated but the problem persists**

Answer (score 1):

After going through 7 hrs of mental blowing up I have solution for the question for i have posted. The reson behind the error was simply bad (empty) assignments in the sheets. Generally if the first item in the sheet is empty then this becomes bad assignment in array and the query fails to detect the comman type of data. So it takes the headers as data. To avoid this always populate the first set of data in the sheet to make sure the query can detect the type of data and treat headers as headers and not data.

Comment: thanks for this reply, i got the same issue, i will fetch my own spreadsheet